# Handling CORS and then request not passing to @WebFilter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I've been working on a Java Spring Boot application for a while and everything was working correctly with it, including authorisation / authentication.

I recently started working on a front end application in Vue to work with the Spring Boot endpoints and started having CORS error responses whenever sending requests to the endpoints as running both locally.

I utilised the approach from Dan Vega's youtube channel, adding a 'WebSecurityConfig' class with the following code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8081"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

After implementing this, I no longer get CORS related error responses, however I now receive 401 errors to all requests, making me think that requests now aren't flowing through my `@WebFilter` `AuthorisationFilter` class after the CORS filter.

My Java code is up at https://github.com/Bungle1981/Java_SpringBoot_Gym_Backend/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/assessment

Has anyone encountered this or have any solutions please?

Comment: You didn't add your filter to the security filter chain, therefore you are not logged in. Because all your requests have to be authorized you get 401. Your custom filter is added to the servlet chain, but security chain is executed first.

Comment: Thanks @dur, any idea on how to ensure this happens explicitly within this code? I thought it was automatic through Spring component scan.

Comment: There is an `addFilter` methos in the chain. But you also to remove `@WebFiler` to only apply the filter once.